# How to fix the JS error: The user agent does not support public key credentials

Tags: javascript, webauthn

I am using the new PasswordCredential API and created this piece of code. It's working. But for some users, it throws this error `The user agent does not support public key credentials.`

```
if (window.PasswordCredential) {
    navigator.credentials.get({
        password: true,
        mediation: 'optional'
    }).then(credential => {
        if (credential) {
        if (credential.type === 'password') {
            // authenticate the user with obtained credentials
        }
    });
}
```

Although I am not using that API, I get that error for many of our users. So, should I check for both condition here like this:

`if (window.PasswordCredential && typeof(PublicKeyCredential) != "undefined" ) {`

if so, why should I do this check for both?

Comment: Related, unanswered question: [Occasional NotSupportedError exception using WebAuthn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59939695/215552)

Comment: I mean, you could just do `if (window.PasswordCredential && window.PublicKeyCredential) {` instead of doing two different types of checks, but I expect that in some browsers, the `credentials.get` call attempts to use the `PublicKeyCredential` code path, triggering the error, instead of looking at your options and seeing that the `publicKey` option is undefined.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for the response. I am fixing it now with this code as specified `if (window.PasswordCredential && window.PublicKeyCredential) {` and let me observe if the user still gets this error on the console.

Comment: Which browser do you get the error in? And do you know at which line you get that exception?

Comment: @agektmr I could only see the user browser. It is Chrome Mobile Version 38.0.1025. Andriod OS. But I couldn't see the line where this error occurs.

Comment: It is about user's browser, you can use this one to check https://caniuse.com/#search=webauthn

Comment: same problem I use iframe to load the page that use google credential api I think it not support iframe